# C# - Put newline "\n" into a string before I reach the stringnumber n

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio, list

at the moment I need a simple idea of my problem, because my last idea was bullsh*t.
I have a string from a List which contains an amount of stringnumbers.

```
1.0, 1.1, 2.0, ..., 10.1, 10.2, 10.2.1, ...
```

Now I want to put an /n into the string for a new line before the first digit will be changed. And the new line should be set before the commata.

For example:

```
1.0, 1.1\n, 2.0\n, 3.0, ..., 5.0, 5.1\n, 6.0, ..., 10.1, 10.2, 10.2.1, ...
```

Do you know a better and efficient way?

Regards, C

Comment: Please take a tour of the help center- https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code?

Comment: Show code for your last idea please. That'll be a place to start at least.

Comment: Okay sorry. Im new here. :S I will post my idea in the next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for integer with `(n % 1 == 0)` to see if your first digit is going to change or not.

```
var input = "1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.2.1";
string result = string.Empty;
var temp = input.Split(','); //You can also trim here as @Steve did
foreach (var item in temp)
{
   //cast it to double, then check if it's an integer
   if ((double.Parse(item.Trim())) % 1 == 0)
   {
       //this is an integer, the first digit will be changed, put "\n"
       result += "\n" + item;
   }
   else
   {
       //this is not an integer, continue as usual.
       result += item;
   }
}

//on this line the variable result is formatted the way you want.
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped me! :)

Answer (score 1):

For fun....

```
string input = "1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.5, 3.0, 3.7, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 5.9, 6.2, 6.7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 8.7, 8.8, 10.1, 10.2, 10.2.1, 10.2.3";

// Split at comma
var temp = input.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());

// Creates an IEnumerable with the strings grouped for their initial value
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                        .Select(x => string.Join(",", 
                            temp.Where(c => c.StartsWith(x.ToString() + "."))));

// Rejoin the strings in a single string excluding empty ones
string final = string.Join(Environment.NewLine + "," , 
                      result.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
Console.WriteLine(final);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. :)